# When a thread/process crashes on acquired DB locks, how does DB detects that and releases the lock?

Tags: mysql, locking, connections, docker, crash

Take MySQL as an example, say a thread run `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` crashes before committing the update, how does MySQL detect the crash and release the lock?

I assume most RMDBS will have some keep-alive timeout and/or other detection of stale connections. But I can't find the exact document for MySQL. If it indeed uses keep-alive timeout, how long will MySQL decide the connection is bad and release the lock?

If it is not keepalive what is it then for MySQL?

--- update ---

I found 2 related questions

1. [Setting a time limit for a transaction in MySQL/InnoDB](https://serverfault.com/questions/241823/setting-a-time-limit-for-a-transaction-in-mysql-innodb)
2. [MySQL rollback on transaction with lost/disconnected connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936699/mysql-rollback-on-transaction-with-lost-disconnected-connection)

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way.  All the changes in a transaction have a trx_id associated with them.  Until there is a `COMMIT`, any inserts/updates/etc are "pending".  After some form of crash, the un-committed trx_ids are cleaned up.

And think of the trx_id as being a 'timestamp'.  This helps when you get into understanding transaction isolation modes (read-uncommitted, dirty, read_committed, etc)

Also, note that while transactions have locks on rows, there are multiple 'versions' of those rows kept in what is called a "history list".  This gets cleaned up later.

Or, another way.  When a change is made (eg insert a row), that row is actually put in the database table, but with a flag (like that trx_id) saying that it is not yet committed.  In another place (the "undo" log), a record is kept that this needs cleaning out in case of a crash.

There are deadlocks and timeouts.  InnoDB has an effective way to discover a deadlock quickly.  At that point, one of the conflicting transactions is told to ROLLBACK; the other is allowed to continue.

There are not-quite-deadlock cases where one thread can simply wait for access to a row.  This is controlled by `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`, which defaults to 50 seconds (much too high in my opinion).  If it can't get the lock it needs within that time, it is ROLLBACK'd.

I don't think there is a "keep-alive" other than to *restart* the server (`mysqld`) as if there had been a power failure.

`SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` acquires a lock on the relevant row(s) so that other threads won't mess with the rows before the transaction has a chance to change them.  Normally, these lock(s) are dealt with, as with other locks, at COMMIT or ROLLBACK or crash time or lock_wait_timeout or etc.

See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67807396/1766831